# What is this 1" growth cluster that formed over night

Tags: mold

This grew overnight on ceiling. There are some brown stains on the ceiling near it. but only there.  No where else in home.  Have not touched them byt they look spongy.
 Live in central Florida in manufactured home. House is always clean and pet free. The air conditioning is on during the day and it has not been very humid.  Any one ever see this before?[image]

Comment: Anything that grows that quickly is probably a fungus. I've seen them pop up on our outdoor furniture. It looks like maybe there's some moisture coming from above. Is it possible that there's a plumbing leak from above?

Comment: Not only that, but if it grew that blob overnight then it's in its reproductive phase (yay, spores!). You likely have more fungus "roots" in the material it has grown out of. Be careful when removing it to minimize distribution of spores, and check for damp in the substrate. You may need to replace some of the substrate if it has gone deeper than the surface.

Comment: Mud Dauber wasps will build things that look like that, seen any wasps hanging around?

Comment: The brown stains around it indicate that there's moisture coming from somewhere; almost certainly from above. The photo is a little blurry; is that a drop-tile ceiling? If so, move the tiles aside and check above for leaks. If not, you still need to check for leaks; it's just harder and might require professional assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do--and you're going to have to anyway no matter what is--is to cut a hole to inspect further. Make sure to open windows and wear a mask, eye glasses, and safety gloves.

Comment: In what are you suggesting a hole be cut?

Comment: The ceiling I would assume.